# WinForm transparente con panel semi-transparente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, .net

he estado tratando de hacer este menú usando WinForm.

[image: Dashboard que quiero hacer]

Ya he intentado con KeyTrasparent del Form, pongo el Form transparente y un panel semi transparente pero solo pasa esto:

[image: Ejemplo de mi programa]

Y cree el panel transparente creando una nueva clase extendiendo de Panel

```
    public class PanelTraslucido : Panel
    {

        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;

        int opacity = 50;

        public int Opacity
        {
            get
            {
                return opacity;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0 || value > 100) throw new ArgumentException("Valor entre 0 y 100");
                opacity = value;
            }
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;

                return cp;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity * 255 / 100, BackColor)))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

    }
```

Y en todo lo que investigue este efecto se puede hacer con WPF y algunas nugets, pero finalmente ambos son .NET y tal vez se puede lograr el mismo efecto con WinForms
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debe de poner código a la pregunta o se la van  a  poner mala

Comment: utiliza MetroFramework son basicamante los mismos objetos que visual studio y eso que quieres hacer lo tienen en sus propiedades.

Comment: Si quieres esos efectos olvídate de Windows forms y trabaja con WPF.